# Expo Notifications Not Working After App Build "expo": "~49.0.8"

Tags: android, firebase, react-native, expo, firebase-cloud-messaging

1. **I followed the Expo documentation for notifications, and they work fine in Expo Go app. However, after building my app, notifications don't seem to be working. The code aligns with Expo guidelines, and there are no errors during the build. Any ideas on what might be causing this issue?**

`

- EXPO SDK 49.0.8
- REACT 18.2.0
- EXPO-NOTIFICATIONS: 0.20.1
  `

`
app.json
"android": {
"useNextNotificationsApi":true,
"adaptiveIcon": {
"foregroundImage": "./assets/logo.png",
"backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
},
"googleServicesFile": "./google-services.json",
"package": "com.myapp.app"
},

`

1. **I followed the Expo documentation for notifications, and they work fine in Expo Go app. However, after building my app, notifications don't seem to be working. The code aligns with Expo guidelines, and there are no errors during the build. Any ideas on what might be causing this issue?**

Comment: Expo documentation mentions that push notifications wont work in an emulator you will need to use a device. If you are, then most likely your permissions might not be setup properly.  Make sure on your `app.json` you have your permissions mentioning: `RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED, SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM`

Comment: did you upload the FCM Server Key on Expo Server? They need it to send android notifications on prod environment

Answer (score 0):

Try to hardcode the **projectId** in your Code. You can Find it in your **app.json**.

**Example Code:**

```
const expoPushToken = await Notifications.getExpoPushTokenAsync({   
projectId: 'your-project-id',   });
```